# How to correct this code? I am trying to get the date function based on a cases

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to use the case function to get values based on the previous date. And if the previous date is the weekend I would like to avoid that date and get the last friday. So eg. when the day is Monday, I would like the values as of Friday.

I have tried the following code, just a summary of the date aspect, but it keeps showing me this error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression
00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 3 Column: 2
```

The code is as follows:

```
Select
A11.Fact_Date Fact_Date,
From XX.X_XX_XX_XX a11
where (A11.Fact_Date = 
Case   
When To_Char(SYSDATE, 'd') = 7 Then A11.Fact_Date = (CURRENT_DATE - 2)   
When To_Char(SYSDATE, 'd') = 1 Then A11.Fact_Date = (CURRENT_DATE - 3)
Else A11.Fact_Date = (CURRENT_DATE - 1)
End);
```

This may seem like a stupid question but I would greatly appreciate any help as I am new to using SQL.

Comment: remove the comma in the second line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As well as the stray comma that was pointed out in a comment, mixing `sysdate` and `current_date` looks odd and could cause weird issues (since they could represent different days); and both contain the time so you probably want to compare your table value against `trunc(case ... end)` - and you don't repeat that column within the clause:

```
select a11.fact_date
from XX.X_XX_XX_XX a11
where a11.fact_date = trunc(
  case
    when to_char(sysdate, 'd') = '1' then sysdate - 3
    when to_char(sysdate, 'd') = '7' then sysdate - 2
    else sysdate - 1
  end);
```

or perhaps with a simple case expression instead of a searched one (also treating the `d` value as a number):

```
select a11.fact_date
from XX.X_XX_XX_XX a11
where a11.fact_date = trunc(sysdate)
  - case to_number(to_char(sysdate, 'd'))
      when 1 then 3
      when 7 then 2
      else 1
    end;
```

However, the `d` day string/number value is dependent on your NLS settings, so it might be safer - and perhaps clearer - to use day names (forced to a specific language to avoid further NLS issues):

```
select a11.fact_date
from XX.X_XX_XX_XX a11
where a11.fact_date = trunc(sysdate)
  - case to_char(sysdate, 'FMDay', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE=ENGLISH')
      when 'Monday' then 3
      when 'Sunday' then 2
      else 1
    end;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=cdd0b9157f0502a9eab4ae3cec488909) showing all three queries in two territories; notice the different results for the first two queries, and that the third is the same regardless of NLS settings.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Really appreciate your time and effort